# flex and bison: C++ user-defined class

Tags: c++, class, compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer

I can't understand how to embed C++ user-defined class into `bison` parser. Here is what I have (just some necessary pieces; if you need, I can post all code).

`scanner.l`

```
%{
#include "parser.tab.h"
#include "types.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define YY_DECL extern "C" int yylex()
using namespace std;
int chars = 0;
int words = 0;
int lines = 0;
extern "C" {
  int yylex(void);
} /* extern "C" */
%}

%%
"none" {
  yylval.none_value = none_type();
  return NONE;
} /* none type */

{DIGIT_BIN}|{DIGIT_OCT}|{DIGIT_DEC}|{DIGIT_HEX} {
  yylval.int_value = atoi(yytext);
  return INT;
} /* int type */
```

`parser.y`

```
%{
#include "types.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void yyerror(const char *error) {
  cerr << error << endl;
} /* error handler */
extern "C" {
  int yylex(void);
  int yyparse(void);
  int yywrap() { return 1; }
} /* extern "C" */
%}

%union {
  none_type   none_value; /* HERE IS WHAT I WANT */
  int         int_value;
} /* union */

%token <none_value>      NONE
%token <int_value>       INT
```

`types.h`

```
#include <iostream>

class none_type {
  public:
    none_type(void);
    ~none_type();
}; /* none_type */
```

As you see the code here is not full, but it should be enough to describe what I want. Everything what I do with default C++ types works well; can I implement my own classes?

Compiler returns such errors:

```
parser.y:20:3: error: 'none_value' does not name a type
In file included from scanner.l:3:0:
parser.y:20:3: error: 'none_value' does not name a type
scanner.l: In function 'int yylex()':
scanner.l:54:32: error: cannot convert 'none_type' to 'int' in assignment
make: *** [caesar] Error 1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't have class types in the `%union`. You can have pointers though.

Comment: I don't understand why you want a void type at all, or is this just an example? You could just let NONE have an int type and never refer to its value.

Comment: @rici: that was just an example. I wanted something like `Python`'s `None` type, I'm not sure whether it is like `void` in `C/C++`.

Comment: `void` in `C` has no value, so it's not really like `None`. Anyway, flex/bison is not strongly typed the way Python is. There are no runtime types; you need to know the type of every value in order to use it. So in this particular case, you're probably better off just using an `int` with default value 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I compile your code with bison/g++ I get the errors:

```
parser.y:16:15: error: member ‘none_type YYSTYPE::none_value’ with constructor not allowed in union
parser.y:16:15: error: member ‘none_type YYSTYPE::none_value’ with destructor not allowed in union
parser.y:16:15: note: unrestricted unions only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x
```

which tells you exactly what the problem is -- you can't put a non-POD type in a union, because the compiler can't tell which ctor/dtor to call for it.  Note the comment that you CAN do it in C++ 11, but that doesn't really help, since in that case it won't call the ctor/dtor for you automatically, so stuff will simply not be cunstructed or destroyed properly.

Comment: Thanks! Since it is the only answer and it is correct too, I mark it as accepted. I have only one question: what way would you go to solve this problem? How about the way which @rici suggests? May be you have better solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to play with putting genuine objects on your stack, then please, have a look at the current master branch of Bison, where you can run examples such as the following

```
%token <::std::string> TEXT;
%token <int> NUMBER;
%token END_OF_FILE 0;
%type <::std::string> item;
%type <::std::list<std::string>> list;
%printer { yyoutput << $$; } <int> <::std::string> <::std::list<std::string>>;

%%

result:
  list  { std::cout << $1 << std::endl; }
;

list:
  /* nothing */ { /* Generates an empty string list */ }
| list item     { std::swap ($$, $1); $$.push_back ($2); }
;

item:
  TEXT          { std::swap ($$, $1); }
| NUMBER        { $$ = string_cast ($1); }
;
%%

// The yylex function providing subsequent tokens:
// TEXT         "I have three numbers for you:"
// NUMBER       1
// NUMBER       2
// NUMBER       3
// TEXT         " and that's all!"
// END_OF_FILE

static
yy::parser::symbol_type
yylex ()
{
  static int stage = -1;
  ++stage;
  yy::parser::location_type loc(0, stage + 1, stage + 1);
  switch (stage)
  {
    case 0:
      return yy::parser::make_TEXT ("I have three numbers for you.", loc);
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
      return yy::parser::make_NUMBER (stage, loc);
    case 4:
      return yy::parser::make_TEXT ("And that's all!", loc);
    default:
      return yy::parser::make_END_OF_FILE (loc);
  }
}
```

Having opinions from possible users of this feature would be most useful.  For instance on help-bison at gnu.org.  See https://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=bison for Git access to the repository.